# Entering data once for multiple records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

One main purpose of a database is to make user entry concise - enter data once and reuse/display that data in different places without requiring the user to enter it again.

In my database, I sometimes have identical data I need to enter in many records, for example, ages of employees. Perhaps I know that 10 employees I just hired are all age 25. Instead of entering 25 once for all employees, I'm looking for a way to enter the number 25 once, and let me select all employees I want to apply the data to. That way, click once to open the form, I type 2 characters, and click 10 times to select 10 employees, and then click once to close (total 12 clicks 2 characters typed) as opposed to clicking to open a form 10 times, typing 2 characters 10 times, and closing the form 10 times (total 20 clicks, 20 characters typed)

Basically, using an access form, how can I type one value, or select one combo box item, and apply it to multiple records with the same column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle: Your employees table has a Yes/no field. You create a continuous form showing their ID, names and the Yes/no field. You click yes for all employees. The yes/no:True is a parameter in an update query.
The update query has the employee ID, the yes/no where True and another field that you want to update. Each time you to want to run the procedure you amend the query as required in the 'other' field, close it, open the form, make your selections as to who is to be updated and run the query, probably by a command button. As it's an action query I would also include in the command button some sort of warning via MsgBox.

Comment: I can imagine this getting the list of 10 employees that need to be updated, but how does it allow you to enter "25" for age one time, instead of 25 for those 10 employees?

Assume the 10 employees are the only employees in the table, or already designated by "need age to be updated = true"

Comment: In the update query you say that you want to update the age of all selected employees to 25. The update query does this for all employees in the form you tick. So you tick 25 employees on the form, click the command button and job done. I'm on my laptop at the moment with no mouse. If you like I'll give detailed help later. Best wishes.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy and paste the value with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V. That will make 1 + 25 keystrokes = 26 keystrokes.

No programming will beat that.

While the users have fun with this, you can concentrate on core stuff of the application.

Comment: The example I used was to illustrate a point, in reality my users have to do this for thousands of items. Do you feel like copying and pasting with shortcuts thousands of times multiple times a day?

poor solution.

Comment: Of course not. But that was not what you wrote originally. It helps if you provice correct details initially.